# Calculate the arc length of the curve $\int _Lydl\:$,where $L$ - the arc $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

Calculate the arc length of the curve $\int _Lydl\:$,where $L$ - the arc $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Use the formula $$ L=\int _a^b\sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx$$

We shall find the derivative. What's next? How to find the limits of integration?

Comment: The limits of integration must be given by the problem.

Comment: They are not. I totally wrote condition.

Comment: Then probably they are just $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So I ask, how to find them.

Comment: Just a head's up, the actual formula is: $$\int_a^b \sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx$$

Comment: @FundThmCalculus. i have fixed that.

Comment: Only from the information presented above, you cannot find any specific endpoints. Either there is something information missing, or you are supposed to use some generic points $a, b \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $y' = \frac {-x} {\sqrt {1-x^2}}$, so $1 + (y') ^2 = \frac 1 {1-x^2}$, therefore you have to compute $\int \limits _a ^b \frac 1 {\sqrt {1-x^2}} \Bbb d x$, which is precisely $\arcsin x \big| _a ^b = \arcsin b - \arcsin a$.

Comment: I choose the right formula?

Answer (score -1):

we will use the fact that $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is the part of the unit circle in the upper half plane. therefore  the arc length is  $$L = \int _a^b\sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx= \cos^{-1}(a) - \cos^{-1} (b).$$

Comment: What am I to do next?

Comment: @andre, what do you mean? is there more than finding the arc length?

Comment: I do not know what to do with it: $\cos^{-1}b - \cos^{-1} a$

Comment: Those are functions (arccos to be specific) which you can evaluate on a calculator or leave as is.

Comment: @AlexM., yes. i have fixed that.

Comment: I actually chose the right formula?

Comment: You get $\sin ^{-1}$, not $\cos ^{-1}$.

Comment: @AlexM., $\sin^{-1}(x) + \cos^{-1} x = \pi/2$

Comment: I misread that as $\cos ^{-1} (b) - \cos ^{-1} (a)$ (note the order of the arguments). I apologize. I've cancelled my downvote.